# php is displayed in my html page, and isn't displaying the data from my DB

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new in PHP and I don't understand the issue encountered while trying to display data from my DB in localhost.

Actually the browser display part of my php code
[phph error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkAwd.png)

here is the code linked with the issue :

```
<?php $reponse = $connexion->query('SELECT * FROM projet_sp');
    ?>

    <table>
            <tr>
                                <th class="CelluleTab11"> Num dossier </th>
                                <th class="CelluleTab12"> Nom projet </th>
                                <th class="CelluleTab13"> DAS </th>
                                <th class="CelluleTab14"> Categorie projet </th>
                                <th class="CelluleTab15"> theme </th>
                                <th class="CelluleTab16"> Pole leader </th>
                                <th class="CelluleTab17"> Porteur </th>
                                <th class="CelluleTab18"> College porteur </th>
            </tr>
                            <?php//On affiche les lignes du tableau une à une à l'aide d'une boucle
                while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
                {
                echo
                "<td class='CelluleTab2'>". $donnees['N?']."</td>"
                "<td class='CelluleTab2'>". $donnees['Nom du projet']."</td>"
                "<td class='CelluleTab2'>" .$donnees['DAS']."</td>"
                "<td class='CelluleTab2'>". $donnees['Cat. de projet']."</td>"
                "<td class='CelluleTab2'>". $donnees['Th?me']."</td>"
                "<td class='CelluleTab2'>" .$donnees['P?le Leader']."</td>"
                "<td class='CelluleTab2'>" .$donnees['Porteur']."</td>"
                "<td class='CelluleTab2'>". $donnees['College Porteur']."</td>";
                }
             ?>
```

I don't have any clue of the origin of the problem.

I'll be gratefull if someone could help.

Thank you !

Edit : this is not all my code displayed in the page, just part of the PHP inside of my HTML tags, see picture link.

Comment: And hello by the way , sorry for the rudness!

Comment: `N?` do you really have a column of that name? and `P?le Leader`

Comment: Hello, Funk Forty Niner, actually the is a little UTF-8 encoding issue on my DB, but as it is a fake DB for a visual, I'm not so much concerned about it at the moment.

Comment: Are you showing all your code? There doesn't seem to be an issue in it, I think, and the code `echo "" "" "" ""` isn't in it.

Comment: All code that is concerned I guess , because for the other parts , it is simple HTML. But thanks for your concern Adder.